# Optimization Word Problem: Hard time setting up the objective function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

So the biggest problem that I have with these questions is to establish an objective function. It really irks me that I can do all the steps after setting up the equation, but without it, Im obviously stuck. So for this word problem:

A 10 inch piece of wire will be cut, and the 2 pieces will be formed into an equilateral triangle and a square. Find the dimensions of the two figures that yield a minimum total area.

So its quite obvious they are looking for a minimum function but how do I set up an objective function to work with, get the derivative, take the critical points, evaluate them and the whole nine yards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for minimum area, so let's start with that. $A_{square} = s^2$, $A_{triangle} = {1 \over 2} bh$. Now, this is an equilateral triangle, so with a little trig, we get $h= \sqrt{b^2 -{b\over 2}^2}$. Now we calculate circumference. $C_{square} = 4s$, $C_{triangle} = 3b$. So put it all together and we get:
$$A_{total} = s^2+{1 \over 2}b\sqrt{b^2-{b\over 2}^2}$$
with $$4s + 3b = 10$$